# How to get last record of duplicate data using group by in Laravel SQL

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-7

I want to retrieve last record of multiple row of same id using GroupBy in my laravel project.

table `purchases`
[image: purchases table]

query in laravel controller

```
DB::table('purchase_transactions')
                        ->where('due_amount','>', 0)
                        ->groupBy('purchases_id')
                        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                        ->get(['purchases_id', DB::raw('MAX(id) as id')]);
```

**output**
[image: query result]

But Only `id no 3` will be the output cause only id no 3 purchases id has due amount.

How to solve this? Anybody Help please?

Comment: I think a more refined question of yours is to get all rows with purchase_ids where due_amount > 0. Am I right?

Comment: @nice_dev.....yes

Comment: Is there any column where you are storing the total amount to be paid for each purchase_id? I presume this is something like EMI mode of payment.

Comment: there is another table named `purchases_transaction_tbl` which is linkedup with this `purchases_tbl` with `purchases_id` column. This table is used for purchase ingredients from suppliers for a restaurant project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your requirement, you can add a simple [`havingRaw`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#havingraw-orhavingraw) condition where the sum of due amount is greater or equal to the paid amount till now.

```
DB::table('purchase_transactions')
    ->groupBy('purchases_id')
    ->havingRaw('sum(due_amount) >= sum(paid_amount)')
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->get(['purchases_id', DB::raw('MAX(id) as id')]);
```

**Note:** The above query assumes that if total paid amount is greater than the total due amount, then all due is paid off and that the rows are maintained in its mathematical uniformity for each `purchase_id`.

If `total bill amount/net payable amount` is in another table then need to inner join that table with this query and little change in `havingRaw()` function. See the below query

```
DB::table('purchase_transactions')
    ->join('purchases', 'purchases.purchases_id', '=', 'purchase_transactions.purchases_id')
    ->groupBy('purchase_transactions.purchases_id')
    ->havingRaw('sum(purchases.net_payable_amount) > sum(purchase_transactions.paid_amount)')
    ->orderBy('purchase_transactions.updated_at', 'desc')
    ->get(['purchase_transactions.purchases_id as purchases_id', DB::raw('MAX(purchase_transactions.id) as id')]);
```

Comment: if total amount 60, paid amount 40 & due amount 20....for this your sql query is not working because here we see `->havingRaw('sum(due_amount) >= sum(paid_amount)')`.......so if paid amount is greater than due amount then the query is not working.....How to solve that?

Comment: @Raff So you wish to get this record as well? Where is the total amount `60` stored?

Comment: @nice_dev....total amount is saving in another table

Comment: @Raff in that case, inner join between these 2 tables can solve the issue.

Comment: Solved it . Thanks again :)

Comment: @nice_dev...I have updated your answer. Please recheck. Thanks

Comment: @Raff Glad you figured it out, approved your edit :)